# Android manifest Shows Error While uploading app on playstore

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the `android:exported` property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. I add `android:exported` on LAUNCHER too but still getting same warning while uploading app on playstore.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.skdevs.status">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="com.skdevs.status.util.YouApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.SplashScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.AboutUs" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.PrivacyPolice" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Login" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Register" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.ForgetPassword" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.EnterReferenceCode"/>
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.DeleteAccount" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.RewardPointClaim" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Verification" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.ContactUs" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Faq" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.EarnPoint" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.StatusDetail" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.StatusSaver" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.DownloadStatusDetail" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.ViewImage" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.ImageUpload"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.GIFUpload"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.QuotesUpload"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Language" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.UploadStatus" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.VideoPlayer"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.VideoUpload"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.AllComment"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.AVStatus" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Suspend" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.AccountVerification" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.Spinner" />
        <activity android:name="com.skdevs.status.activity.TDView" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" /> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.util.NotificationExtenderExample"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.service.VideoUploadService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.service.DownloadVideoService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.service.DownloadIGService"
            android:exported="false" />
        <service
            android:name="com.skdevs.status.service.UIGService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `android:exported="true"` in your Launcher activity itself.
[image]

> From [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12):

so there must be `android:exported="false"` in your `CustomTabActivity`

add this line in your application tag; `tools:replace="android:exported"`

```
<application 
tools:replace="android:exported" >

</application>
```

Comment: It returns error if i set it to false, Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs.

Comment: @CodeslideCreation share that log please

Comment: android:exported
  ADDED from [com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:2.2.0] C:\Users\choos\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ab04651e7b4c4654a87e704158154c9c\jetified-transport-runtime-2.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:34:13-37
 android:name
  ADDED from [com.google.android.datatransport:transport-runtime:2.2.0] C:\Users\choos\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ab04651e7b4c4654a87e704158154c9c\jetified-transport-runtime-2.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:33:13-132  Like this

Comment: i am looking for this line in log.. Manifest merger failed.. post it in your question with edit

Comment: Attribute activity#com.facebook.CustomTabActivity@exported value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:119:13-37
 is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-common:5.15.3] AndroidManifest.xml:37:13-36 value=(true).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:exported"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:117:9-128:20 to override.

Comment: add this line tools:replace="android:exported" in your <application> start tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250520/discussion-between-codeslide-creation-and-bhoomika-patel).

Comment: still same error.